# INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). Error

Tags: python, ethereum, chainlink

I have a problem with using brownie compile in Visual Studio Code as I get a INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Share your code in markdown to make it reproducible, thanks.

Comment: Could you please copy paste your code instead of an image?

Comment: It is worth to mention the general meaning of the error message "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).". It appears if you trigger those internals of Windows which search a program in the PATH, for example if you run "where" command (e.g. `where something_invalid.exe`) in the batch console. The `pattern(s)` mentioned in the error message are stored in the PATHEXT environment variable which is used if you don't specify the file extension. Understanding of this fact can help you to find the cause of the error which is wrong PATH in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue, it actually means it's working fine!

Comment: I get the same problem If everything is fine, then that persistent message is kinda sloppy and should be removed right?

Comment: This would be a nice issue to make on the brownie repo!

Comment: Patrick - I enjoy your videos. But this answer is not very helpful. As a guy who likes to explain how everything works, wouldn't it be better to explain where the message is coming from, why it is showing up, and how to suppress it - if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.sol` file is in the `build/contracts` folder. Move it to `contracts` folder.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a similar issue when I am compiling my .sol file using python. Everything works perfectly though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31336380)

Answer (score 0):

This issues occurs if you didn't define the correct path variable to the flutter\bin folder in the environment variables for your account in windows.

Open this link to see how solve:

https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/200/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34452632)